# Adding missing items to collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have two collections from different classes that have these two commpon properties:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string ItemID {get;set;}
    public int sales {get;set;}
}

public class Class2 
{
    public string ItemID {get;set;}
}
```

Now what happens here I have two collections with these types of classes like this:

```
List<Class1> list1; // has items that actually have sales...

List<Class1> list2; // has all items that have or don't have sales
```

`list1` is missing items that don't have sales at all. And what I would like to do here is somehow compare these two lists by the `itemID`, and if the `itemID` is missing, then I'm gonna add the missing item to `list1` with setting property `sales` to 0 manually.

And when the missing item is found, then i'd like to do this:

```
list1.Add(new Class1
{
    Sales = 0,
    ItemID = ItemID,
});
```

Or some other way to add the missing items and setting their property `sales` to 0...

Can someone help me out?

Edit:

Guys I think i hve more explaining to do... So basically if the ItemID from Class2 list isn't present in Class1 list, then it's added to Class1 list with property "Sales" set to 0....

Comment: Use a Join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Why you told us about `Class2` does this class involved somehow?

Comment: @Fabio yes because it contains all items, the ones that have sales, and the ones that don't have sales... Class1 list has only the items with sales

Comment: `Class2` just hold a `string`

Comment: @KernelMode yes correct :)... But if the ItemID which is present in Class2 list, isn't there in Class1 list, then it's sales are set to 0...

Comment: Did you tried anything? Something about: `var missingItems = list2.Where(class2 => list1.Any(class1 => class1.ItemId == class2.ItemId) == false).Select(class2 => new Class1 { itemId = class2.ItemId, Sales = 0 });`, then `list1.AddRange(missingItems);`

Comment: From one hand, `Class2` just holds a `string`. From the other hand, it holds "all the the items". Can you explain this gap?

Comment: @Fabio yes that's it! Thanks :) If u wanna reply as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @KernelMode when I mentioned "all the items" I ment all ItemID's ... Sorry about that ..

Comment: `default(int) == 0`, no need to even set `Sales` (or is it `sales`? It seems that your code isn't consistent.) Is `list2` supposed to be a `List<Class2>`?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - explicitly setting default value can be good "documentation", because it is part of business logic

Comment: Is `List<Class1> list2;` a typo? Seems like you meant `List<Class2> list2;`, if I'm reading your question properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
var missingItems = 
    list2.Where(class2 => list1.Any(class1 => class1.ItemId == class2.ItemId) == false)
         .Select(class2 => new Class1 
         { 
             ItemId = class2.ItemId, 
             Sales = 0 
         });

list1.AddRange(missingItems);
```

For better performance of `Where` clause your can create `HashSet<string>` of `list1`.

```
var existedIds = new HashSet<string>(list1.Select(class1 => class1.ItemId));
var missingItems = 
    list2.Where(class2 => existedIds.Contains(class2.ItemId) == false)
         .Select(class2 => new Class1 
         { 
             ItemId = class2.ItemId, 
             Sales = 0 
         }); 

list1.AddRange(missingItems);
```